# How to find objects in array where inner array might include other objects by using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have the following arrays:

```
const tasks = [
  {id: 0, name: 'a', tags: [{id: 0, name: 'q'}, {id: 1, name: 'w'}]},
  {id: 1, name: 'b', tags: [{id: 2, name: 'e'}, {id: 4, name: 't'}, {id: 11, name: 's'}]},
  {id: 2, name: 'c', tags: []},
  {id: 3, name: 'd', tags: [{id: 0, name: 'q'}, {id: 3, name: 'r'}, {id: 7, name: 'i'}]},
  {id: 6, name: 'g', tags: [{id: 7, name: 'i'}, {id: 4, name: 't'}]},
]

const tags = [
  {id: 0, name: 'q'},
  {id: 1, name: 'w'},
  {id: 2, name: 'e'},
  {id: 3, name: 'r'},
  {id: 4, name: 't'},
  {id: 7, name: 'i'},
  {id: 11, name: 's'}
]

let selectedTags = [0, 5]
```

`selectedTags` is an Array of indexes of `tags` Array. Now I need to find all objects in `tasks` Array, where property `tags` includes any of the selected tags. So in this case the output should be:

```
let result = [
  {id: 0, name: 'a', tags: [{id: 0, name: 'q'}, {id: 1, name: 'w'}]},
  {id: 3, name: 'd', tags: [{id: 0, name: 'q'}, {id: 3, name: 'r'}, {id: 7, name: 'i'}]},
  {id: 6, name: 'g', tags: [{id: 7, name: 'i'}, {id: 4, name: 't'}]}
]
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
let result= []
_.forEach(selectedTags, index => {
  const tagId = tags[index].id
  result = _.filter(tasks, task => _.some(task.tags, ['tag.id', tagId]))
})
```

but I'm ending up with an empty array. I tried to use map, find and some other lodash methods, but so far nothing worked.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: You're overwriting `result` each time through the `_.forEach` loop, not combining the results from previous iterations.

Comment: There's no `tag` property to match `tag.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reassigning the filtered array in each iteration, also you're passing to the function `.some` an array, however, you should pass a key-value object instead.

The following approach used two nested calls of function `.some` for checking `tags.id` vs `selectedTag` ids,

```js
const tasks = [  {id: 0, name: 'a', tags: [{id: 0, name: 'q'}, {id: 1, name: 'w'}]},  {id: 1, name: 'b', tags: [{id: 2, name: 'e'}, {id: 4, name: 't'}, {id: 11, name: 's'}]},  {id: 2, name: 'c', tags: []},  {id: 3, name: 'd', tags: [{id: 0, name: 'q'}, {id: 3, name: 'r'}, {id: 7, name: 'i'}]},  {id: 6, name: 'g', tags: [{id: 7, name: 'i'}, {id: 4, name: 't'}]}],
      tags = [  {id: 0, name: 'q'},  {id: 1, name: 'w'},  {id: 2, name: 'e'},  {id: 3, name: 'r'},{id: 4, name: 't'},  {id: 7, name: 'i'},  {id: 11, name: 's'}],
      selectedTags = [0, 5],
      result = _.filter(tasks, ({tags: itags}) => _.some(itags, ({id}) => _.some(selectedTags, i => tags[i].id === id)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to remove duplicates from the result, it's returning ID:3 twice.

Comment: First of all thank you for your help! Much appreciated! Why did it return also object with ID 1? It doesn't have any of the selected tags

Comment: @Igal weird, with the destructuring assignment it generates that result, I updated the answer removing destructuring assignment.

Comment: @Ele Thank you very much! This time it worked as expected! BTW, your very first solution also worked, I just added `result = _.uniqBy(result, 'id')`. But the last solution is much cleaner! Again, thank you very much!

Comment: @Igal I saw the problem, it's because of the variable tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `filter()` with nested `some()`

```js
const tasks = [
  {id: 0, name: 'a', tags: [{id: 0, name: 'q'}, {id: 1, name: 'w'}]},
  {id: 1, name: 'b', tags: [{id: 2, name: 'e'}, {id: 4, name: 't'}, {id: 11, name: 's'}]},
  {id: 2, name: 'c', tags: []},
  {id: 3, name: 'd', tags: [{id: 0, name: 'q'}, {id: 3, name: 'r'}, {id: 7, name: 'i'}]},
  {id: 6, name: 'g', tags: [{id: 7, name: 'i'}, {id: 4, name: 't'}]},
]

const tags = [
  {id: 0, name: 'q'},
  {id: 1, name: 'w'},
  {id: 2, name: 'e'},
  {id: 3, name: 'r'},
  {id: 4, name: 't'},
  {id: 7, name: 'i'},
  {id: 11, name: 's'}
]

let selectedTags = [0, 5]
const res = tasks.filter(({tags}) => 
               tags.some(tag => 
                  selectedTags.some(index => tags[index].name === tag.name)
               )
            );
console.log(res)
```

Comment: You're returning task ID 1, which doesn't match either of the selected tags.