# How to find objects in array where inner array includes other objects by using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have the following arrays:

```
const tasks = [
  {id: 0, name: 'a', tags: [{id: 0, name: 'q'}, {id: 7, name: 'i'}]},
  {id: 1, name: 'b', tags: [{id: 2, name: 'e'}, {id: 4, name: 't'}, {id: 2, name: 'e'}, {id: 0, name: 'q'}]},
  {id: 2, name: 'c', tags: []},
  {id: 3, name: 'd', tags: [{id: 7, name: 'i'}, {id: 3, name: 'r'}, {id: 0, name: 'q'}]},
  {id: 6, name: 'g', tags: [{id: 7, name: 'i'}, {id: 4, name: 't'}]},
]

const tags = [
  {id: 0, name: 'q'},
  {id: 1, name: 'w'},
  {id: 2, name: 'e'},
  {id: 3, name: 'r'},
  {id: 4, name: 't'},
  {id: 7, name: 'i'},
  {id: 11, name: 's'}
]

let selectedTags = [0, 5]
```

`selectedTags` is an Array of indexes of `tags` Array. Now I need to find all objects in `tasks` Array, where property `tags` includes ALL of the selected tags. So in this case the output should be:

```
let result = [
  {id: 0, name: 'a', tags: [{id: 0, name: 'q'}, {id: 7, name: 'i'}]},
  {id: 3, name: 'd', tags: [{id: 7, name: 'i'}, {id: 3, name: 'r'}, {id: 0, name: 'q'}]}
]
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
let result= []
_.forEach(selectedTags, index => {
  const tagId = tags[index]._id
  result = _.filter(tasks, task => _.find(task.tags, ['_id', tagId]))
})
```

But the `result` array included objects where `tags` array had only one of the selected tags (always the same tag).

Any ideas, please?

Comment: It looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468021/how-to-find-objects-in-array-where-inner-array-might-include-other-objects-by-us/60468124

Comment: `result` gets overwritten in the forEach loop (that would explain why its always the same/last tag that works)

Comment: Your test data doesn't seem to have the results you say it should, your selected tags is `[0, 5]` but your expected results doesn't have 5, it has 7, is this a typo.?

Comment: @Keith I believe it is the object at index `5` from the `tags` array

Comment: @Ele Yes, it is similar. The difference is here I need to find objects with ALL selected tags, while in the other question it was ANY of the selected.

Comment: @Keith As Nick said, it's the index of an object in `tags` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to map your selectedTags into the equivalent tags array.

Next use `every` to make sure every item in the selectedTags exists in the tasks.tags array using `some`..

Example below..

```js
const tasks = JSON.parse('[{"id":0,"name":"a","tags":[{"id":0,"name":"q"},{"id":7,"name":"i"}]},{"id":1,"name":"b","tags":[{"id":2,"name":"e"},{"id":4,"name":"t"},{"id":2,"name":"e"},{"id":0,"name":"q"}]},{"id":2,"name":"c","tags":[]},{"id":3,"name":"d","tags":[{"id":7,"name":"i"},{"id":3,"name":"r"},{"id":0,"name":"q"}]},{"id":6,"name":"g","tags":[{"id":7,"name":"i"},{"id":4,"name":"t"}]}]');
const tags = JSON.parse('[{"id":0,"name":"q"},{"id":1,"name":"w"},{"id":2,"name":"e"},{"id":3,"name":"r"},{"id":4,"name":"t"},{"id":7,"name":"i"},{"id":11,"name":"s"}]');
let selectedTags = [0, 5];


const result = tasks.filter(f =>
  selectedTags.map(m => tags[m]).every(
    e => f.tags.some(s => s.id === e.id)));

console.log(result);
```

ps.  The `map` could be done separately if performance was a concern.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked flawlessly! I just rewrote it the lodash way: `let result = _.filter(tasks, task => _.every(_.map(selectedTags, i => tags[i]), sTag => _.some(task.tags, tag => tag.id === sTag.id)))`

Answer (score 0):

First build `names` from selectedTags and use `filter` on tasks should work.

```js
const filter = (tasks, tags, selectedTags) => {
  const names = selectedTags.map(tag => tags[tag].name);
  return tasks.filter(task =>
    names.every(name => task.tags.map(x => x.name).includes(name))
  );
};

const tasks = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "a",
    tags: [
      { id: 0, name: "q" },
      { id: 7, name: "i" }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "b",
    tags: [
      { id: 2, name: "e" },
      { id: 4, name: "t" },
      { id: 2, name: "e" },
      { id: 0, name: "q" }
    ]
  },
  { id: 2, name: "c", tags: [] },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "d",
    tags: [
      { id: 7, name: "i" },
      { id: 3, name: "r" },
      { id: 0, name: "q" }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "g",
    tags: [
      { id: 7, name: "i" },
      { id: 4, name: "t" }
    ]
  }
];

const tags = [
  { id: 0, name: "q" },
  { id: 1, name: "w" },
  { id: 2, name: "e" },
  { id: 3, name: "r" },
  { id: 4, name: "t" },
  { id: 7, name: "i" },
  { id: 11, name: "s" }
];

let selectedTags = [0, 5];

console.log(filter(tasks, tags, selectedTags));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However the returned object also includes object with ID 1, which tags array don't have all the selected tags.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't have tag 'i'.

Comment: Ah my bad. [0, 5] didn't realize that these indexes. @Igal, Updated the answer with fix.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `reduce` method and check on every iteration whether an element contains desired tags:

```
const tagsToFind = selectedTags.map(s => tags[s]);

const result = tasks.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (tagsToFind.every(t => c.tags.some(s => s.name == t.name)))
        a.push(c);
    return a;
},[])
```

An example:

```js
const tasks = [
    {id: 0, name: 'a', tags: [{id: 0, name: 'q'}, {id: 7, name: 'i'}]},
    {id: 1, name: 'b', tags: [{id: 2, name: 'e'}, {id: 4, name: 't'}, 
        {id: 2, name: 'e'}, {id: 0, name: 'q'}]},
    {id: 2, name: 'c', tags: []},
    {id: 3, name: 'd', tags: [{id: 7, name: 'i'}, {id: 3, name: 'r'}, 
        {id: 0, name: 'q'}]},
    {id: 6, name: 'g', tags: [{id: 7, name: 'i'}, {id: 4, name: 't'}]},
];

const tags = [
    {id: 0, name: 'q'},
    {id: 1, name: 'w'},
    {id: 2, name: 'e'},
    {id: 3, name: 'r'},
    {id: 4, name: 't'},
    {id: 7, name: 'i'},
    {id: 11, name: 's'}
];

let selectedTags = [0, 5];
const tagsToFind = selectedTags.map(s => tags[s]);

const result = tasks.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (tagsToFind.every(t => c.tags.some(s => s.name == t.name)))
        a.push(c);
    return a;
},[])

console.log(result);
```